# getuid/geteuid strange behaviour

Tags: linux, go

I've got a simple code, which basically looks like:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/sys/unix"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("real: %d, effective: %d\n", unix.Getuid(), unix.Geteuid())
}
```

Which basically outputs the real and effective user id. Now, once build with: `go build main.go`; I also call `sudo chown root:root main && sudo chmod 4755 main` to get `-rwsr-xr-x` permissions on the file.

If I understand the concept of the setuid bit (the `s` part), it allows me later to use setuid in the source file (noting, that I'll have to use either `unix.Setreuid` or `unix.RawSyscall` in conjunction with `runtime.LockOSThread`). Yet, the current compiled code no matter what always returns `real: 1000, effective: 1000`.

At first I thought that maybe it is the case with some Go code, double and tripple checked it, yet, result is still the same. Then I went further and made a mock up in c:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv){
   printf("real: %d, effective: %d\n", getuid(), geteuid());
   fflush(stdout);
}
```

Compiled, chown'ed to `root:root`, chmod'ed to `4755`, and guess what? It still does the very same thing, it outputs `real: 1000, effective: 1000`.

So, if both: Go and C versions once compiled, properly changed in terms of permissions, return the same result: ignoring the setting, this is might to do something with system settings otherwise.

**Update[0]:** I've figured out that such a situation can be caused by a `nosuid` option for the mounted drive; so I've copied the executable to another drive, which doesn't have such an option. Still no effect.

So, what should I do:

1. To fight that behavior?
2. To detect such an environment in future?

Looking forward to see your suggestions.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that there's a bigger problem. This is not related to Go or to C or any other language. There's definitely something else going on in your system. Both your programs work fine on my machine giving `real: 1000, effective: 0`. With that said, since this has not much to do with Go or C, but with your system, you should probably ask on [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, I've figured out the whole issue, just answered my own question so far. The issue indeed was with the `nosuid` option, yet, to fight it I had to compile on a `nosuid` disabled partition.

Comment: I read it, that's nice to know, good job :)

Comment: Also see Chen, Dean and Wagner's [Setuid Demystified](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~daw/papers/setuid-usenix02.pdf).

Comment: @jww, thank you, I'll dig into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More deep research of the `nosuid` option showed that the whole process, including the **compilation** has to happen on the drive mounted **without** `nosuid` option.

So, basically speaking, the steps to fight the issue are:

1. Create a directory on a `nosuid` disabled drive;
2. Ensure directory group is your group;
3. Ensure directory group permissions have `w` option;
4. Copy the source to this directory;
5. `go build` within the directory;
6. Apply `chown root:root` to the result;
7. Apply `chmod 4755` to the result;
8. Enjoy the result from /nonosuid/directory/

And to detect environment you need to search for a destination without `nosuid` parameter during the installation.